# Can't save data into firebase realtime database, only image was save to storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can't save data into firebase realtime database but I was able to save the images into firebase storage. I have used Toast to check if my ref.push.key() generates a key and it does so ref.child(refKey).setValue(Object) should insert my data into realtime database, but It does not insert the data at all.

My firebase reference:

```
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("products_uploads");
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("products_uploads");
```

Method should have save to realtime and storage, but it only save to storage:

```
    private void uploadFile() {
    if (mImageUri != null) {
        StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

        uploadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        uploadProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

        mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> () {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                uploadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                uploadProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                                uploadProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                            }
                        }, 500);

                        Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Product  Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        fileReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                Uri downloadUrl = uri;

                                Product upload = new Product(nameEditText.getText().toString().trim(),
                                        downloadUrl.toString(),
                                        descriptionEditText.getText().toString(),
                                        priceEditText.getText().toString().trim(),
                                        quantityEditText.getText().toString().trim());

                                String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey(); // was able to generate key                               
                                mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload)
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {

                                                Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Inserted to realtime db", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                            }
                                        })
                                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                                Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Exception realtime db"+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                            }
                                        }); 

                               uploadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                openImagesActivity ();                                }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        uploadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> () {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        uploadProgressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't Selected Any file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Realtime database structure

[image]

Storage database structure

[image]

I've added completion listener to my setValue, but it does call onSuccess() or onFailure() as both of Toast does not display. Please advice, thank you.

Also, I noticed the following on log:

`Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://crud-94fb7-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app`

However both realtime and storage are under southeast1, also I checked google-services.json file and it has the correct database URL.

`"project_info": {
    "project_number": "1056142426280",
    "firebase_url": "https://crud-94fb7-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app",
    "project_id": "crud-94fb7",
    "storage_bucket": "crud-94fb7.appspot.com"
  },`

Full log:

```
05/31 11:40:52: Launching 'app' on Xiaomi Redmi K30.
App restart successful without requiring a re-install.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.morales/com.example.morales.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 27706 on device 'xiaomi-redmi_k30-a1bff4e'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
I/FeatureParser: can't find phoenix.xml in assets/device_features/,it may be in /system/etc/device_features
E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
W/example.morales: type=1400 audit(0.0:393296): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_displayfeature_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=27284 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c134,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_displayfeature_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.morales
    getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.morales
    getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    Fail to get file list oat
    getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
I/AdrenoGLES: QUALCOMM build                   : 663be55, I724753c5e3
    Build Date                       : 11/06/19
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.27.05.02
    Local Branch                     : mybranchea006718-00ab-f18a-9c1c-5cb90179c3e0
    Remote Branch                    : quic/gfx-adreno.lnx.1.0.r84-rel
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
    Build Config                     : S P 8.0.12 AArch64
I/AdrenoGLES: PFP: 0x016ee187, ME: 0x00000000
W/AdrenoUtils: : Failed to open /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/gpu_model
    : Failed to read chip ID from gpu_model. Fallback to use the GSL path
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:393297): avc: denied { search } for name="kgsl" dev="sysfs" ino=47468 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c134,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs_kgsl:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:274548146
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@74d94aa
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2676 bytes, containing 1 windows, 14 views
W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://crud-94fb7-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:274562051
W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
W/StorageUtil: no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request
    No App Check token for request.
W/StorageUtil: no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request
    No App Check token for request.
D/UploadTask: Increasing chunk size to 524288
W/StorageUtil: no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request
    No App Check token for request.
D/UploadTask: Increasing chunk size to 1048576
W/StorageUtil: no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest: No App Check token for request.
W/StorageUtil: no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request
    No App Check token for request.
I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.example.morales, PackageName:com.example.morales
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:274573441
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@c3f8da0
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:274595122
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@6fa9b90
```

Comment: You aren't check the call to setValue for errors.  Something could be going wrong and you'd never know.

Comment: I've added completion listener to my setValue, but it does call onSuccess() or onFailure() as both of my Toast does not display.

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) might also help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Rebuild Project solves the problem, I haven't sleep since last night though.

Answer (score -1):

try to:
clean the app and then re-build